# when are default argument object destroyed?

Tags: c++, destructor

```
void foo(const Object & o = Object()) {
      return;
}
```

In the function above, when is ~Object supposed to be called ? when the function exit or when at the end of the block surrounding the call site ?

Comment: I believe the default argument is constructed as part of the function call expression.

Comment: @JesseGood With the implied definition of `Object` it should, AFAIK.

Comment: clang++ says "example.cpp:7:19: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'Object' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Object'".

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Yes, the code was updated with a `const`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default argument will be destroyed at the end of the complete expression that contains the function call.

Comment: i am not sure to understand what you mean by"at the end of the complete expression". Does that mean destructor can be call elsewhere than scope boundaries ?

Comment: @GreyGeek when a temporary object is bound to a reference, the object's lifetime becomes that of the reference. So in this case it will be destroyed when the function returns.

Comment: @SethCarnegie that makes sense, but it's the opposite of what david answers is ...

Comment: @SethCarnegie That is not completely true, it lives until the end of the statement containing the call, like *David* said and further explained in my answer.

Comment: @ChristianRau oh you're right, I forgot the special case. GreyGeek, this answer is right.

Comment: @GreyGeek: Consider: `g(f());`, the call to `f()` is sequenced before `g()`, and thus it must complete before `g()` is called. On the other hand, the temporary created to provide a default argument to `f()` will live until the whole expression completes after `g()` returns.

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate a bit on what *David* said, the standard says in section **12.2 [class.temporary]**:

> There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a
>   different point than the end of the full-expression. [...] The second
>   context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to
>   which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete
>   object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the
>   lifetime of the reference except:
>
> - ...
> - A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full-expression
>     containing the call.
> - ...

So they are neither destroyed when the function exits nor when the block containing the call ends, but at the end of the complete statement that contains the function call (simply said, at the first semicolon after the function call, in the calling context).

**EDIT:** So say we got:

```
int foo(const Object & o = Object());

some_stuff();    
std::cout << (foo() + 7);
other_stuff();
```

This sould be roughly equivalent to the following (mind the conceptual scope block):

```
some_stuff(); 
{
    Object o;             // create temprorary
    int i = foo(o);       // and use it
    int j = i + 7;        // do other things
    std::cout << j;       // while o still alive
}                         // finally destroy o
other_stuff();
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out by *Michael* in his comment, this *"statement/semicolon"*-analogy I gave is rather a simplification of the term *"full-expression"* and there are cases where it is a bit different, like his example:

```
if(foo()) bar();
```

Which would destroy the temporary before `bar` is called and thus be different from the expression statement:

```
foo() ? bar() : 0;
```

But nevertheless, the *"semicolon"*-analogy is often a good fit, even if a full-expression is not neccessarily the same as a statement (which can consist of multiple full-expressions).

Comment: Nitpick: it'll be destroyed at the end of the full expression, which is not necessarily the same as the statement. For example assume that `foo()` returned an int, then in `if (foo()) bar();` the object created as the default argument to `foo()` would be destroyed before calling `bar()` (or whatever follows the `if` statement). So the expression statement `foo() ? bar() : 0;` would have slightly different semantics than the statement `if (foo()) bar();` due to the different times that the `Object()` dtor was called.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Indeed, but with the *"semicolon"*-analogy often used I wanted to simplify the not so obvious *"full-expression"*-phrase. But you give a good example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this code should compile. You can't bind a reference to a temporary unless it's `const`. And if it was `const` the temporary should be kept alive until the end of the function expression. Just the same as a local variable defined within it.